# Show progressbar on top of listview in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, progress-bar, android-relativelayout

I have a listview in RelativeLayout which loads the content automatically from an AsyncTask. Now I want to add a horizontal progressbar on top of the listview so that when the element is loading, it shows the progress (not on an overlay). I tried some method but the progressbar does not show up properly. What is the right way to do?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
    <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listViewTitle"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listViewTitle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `LinearLayout` and switch visability of the `ProgressBar` when starting or finishing loading.

At the moment, you have both views on the top edge of your `RelativeLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you can do this:

```
public static final int DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS = 0;
private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
----
----

   @Override
    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        switch (id) {
        case DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS:
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Downloading data file..");
            mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
            mProgressDialog.setCancelable(false);
            mProgressDialog.show();
            return mProgressDialog;
        default:
            return null;
        }
    }

----
----
In AsyncTask:


    @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            showDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

          ----
          ----
          publishProgress("" + progress);
        }

        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... progress) {
         mProgressDialog.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(progress[0]));
    }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {   
            dismissDialog(DIALOG_DOWNLOAD_PROGRESS);
        }
```

Comment: The question specifies: `... not on an overlay`. Your suggestion (a dialog) won't work then. Can you update your answer?

Answer (score 0):

Both the `ProgressBar` and the `ListView` are aligned to the top. In this case the `ListView` will overlap the `ProgressBar`. Try aligning the `ListView` to be below the `ProgressBar` as:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
                 style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listViewTitle"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/listViewTitle"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
              android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
              android:layout_below="@id/progressBar1" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

For your case, you could be better off using a `LinearLayout` instead of a `RelativeLayout`.